# MFMailComposeViewController is inlining a PDF making it unreadable on windows

Tags: ios, objective-c, email, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

For some reason my app that forwards emails is producing an attachment that doesn't show up in Outlook.

If I attach a single PDF the PDF appears inline in the mail composer window instead of as an attachment.  The resulting email when it's sent is not viewable in Outlook (the attachment is a red X) but it views just fine in Mac Mail.

If I attach multiple PDFs it appears as normal, the PDFs are not inlined and appear on mac/windows as you would expect.

I'm not doing anything odd, this code is very straightforward.  Any ideas as to why a single PDF will not attach to the email as an attachment instead of inline?

```
-(void)startNewEmailTo:(NSArray*)recipients ccList:(NSArray*)ccList withSubject:(NSString*)subject withBody:(NSString*)body withAttachments:(NSSet*)attachments
{
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailVC = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mailVC.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    [mailVC setSubject:subject];
    [mailVC setToRecipients:recipients];
    if (ccList != nil)
        [mailVC setCcRecipients:ccList];
    for (EmailAttachment* attachment in attachments)
    {
        // Get attachment data
        NSString *localFilePath = attachment.fileStatus.localFilePath;
        NSData *attachmentData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:localFilePath];

        // Find the MIME type of the file
        NSString* fullPath = [localFilePath stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
        NSURL* fileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fullPath];
        NSURLRequest* fileUrlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:fileUrl];
        NSError* error = nil;
        NSURLResponse* response = nil;
        [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:fileUrlRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];
        NSString *attachmentMimeType = [response MIMEType];
        // If the mimetype is still unknown just try binary/octet-stream
        if (!attachmentMimeType)
            attachmentMimeType = @"binary/octet-stream";

        // Add the attachment
        [mailVC addAttachmentData:attachmentData mimeType:attachmentMimeType fileName:[attachment displayName]];
    }
    [mailVC setMessageBody:body isHTML:YES];

    [self presentViewController:mailVC animated:YES completion:^(void)
     {
     }];
}
```

**EDIT**  I've discovered this ONLY happens on iPad when the mail composition window is in a popover.  If I try this on an iphone the attachment appears as a normal attachment and works properly.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered that this is a bug in UIKit.  I have been able to reproduce the problem with a sample application.  It only happens on iPad, when emailing a single PDF attachment with an HTML email.

I've filed a bug with apple but there's no telling if/when they'll address it.   If this problem is affecting you , please file a bug and as they find more people filing it, perhaps it will get addressed.

For the record, this problem was encountered on iOS 7.1.2.  I don't know if it was a problem before this or not but this is the current release as of the time of this posting.